# How to move to another view controller in iOS on a Button Click?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I created two `UIViewController` in the Storyboard interface - `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`.

Now I would like to move to `SecondViewController` by tapping on a button in the `FirstViewController`. What should I do to the button? I have <kbd>ctrl</kbd> clicked the button and connected it to the `SecondViewController` using "Reveal view controller push controller". Is there anything else to do in the code?

Comment: Have you embedded everything inside a Navigation Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do everything inside your storyboard, you have to select your FirstViewController and click on Menu Option **Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller**

[image]
**Embed into navigation controller**

[image]

**Connect button with another view**
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but is it necessary to embed it in Navigation Controller?

Comment: also how is the button connected to the second view controller?

Comment: You have to select your button, click with right button and select the view you want to connect. I have edited my answer with a new video where I show you how to do it ;) Hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure FirstViewController is embedded in UINavigationController.
So that when you tap on that button it pushes the SecondViewController properly.

When you have connected your button using control click from button to SecondViewController, you will be able to see seague between your FirstViewController and SecondViewController.
Make sure you give name to segue in attribute inspector.
Suppose you have named "goto".

Now in your FirstViewController, write following code.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goto"]) {

//Data that you want to pass to second view controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but is it necessary to embed it in Navigation Controller?